# CPack: "make package" generates an empty deb package

Tags: linux, cmake, packaging, cpack

I'm using the combination of CMake and CPack to generate a package. This is the `CPack` part of my CMake file:

```
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "Company")
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL exe link configs lastversion script log monitor)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${PRODUCT}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION ${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR ${MAJOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR ${MINOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH ${PATCH})
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "Some Description")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "support@company.com")

include(CPack)
```

On my computer (64bit), executing "make package" gives me a fully functional `.deb` package:

> Run CPack packaging tool...
>   CPack: Create package using DEB
>   CPack: Install projects
>   CPack: - Run preinstall target for: XXX
>   CPack: - Install project: XXX
>   CPack: **Create package**
>   CPack: - package: /home/username/xxx-B-4.0.0.deb generated.

But on another system (32bit Lenny), executing the same command using the same CMake file, gives me an empty `.deb` package. What could be wrong?

The output of 32bit system:

> Run CPack packaging tool...
>   CPack: Create package using DEB
>   CPack: Install projects
>   CPack: - Run preinstall target for: XXX
>   CPack: - Install project: XXX
>   CPack: **Compress package**
>   CPack: **Finalize package**
>   CPack: Package /home/username/xxx-B-4.0.0.deb generated.

I've highlighted the difference between the outputs.

Comment: Is the version of CMake the same ?

Comment: @Barth No, On my computer: `2.8.10.1`, on the other one: `2.6-patch 0`. Is this the source of problem?

Comment: Not sure, but I am looking for discrepancies. You might want to try to upgrade to 2.8. It might be that in 2.6 there is an extra parameter required or something along this line. To be noted that I don't see anything obviously wrong in your configuration.

Comment: @Barth That was it! I installed the newer CMake version and the problem disappeared. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try To use the same version, i.e. 2.8, on both platforms. It might be that in 2.6 there is an extra parameter required or something along this line.